# Use ajax to pass the value of selected dropdown as an argument to a function in another dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, onchange

I need some advice with an ajax function I am building and haven't been able to figure it out so far.
So I have select `order_by` dropdown which uses ajax function called `searchFilter` to change `this.value` which is a variable called `$orderr_by`:

```
<select name="order_by" 
        onchange="searchFilter('0',
                               '<?php echo $maxRows;?>',
                               this.value);">
```

I have another select `condition` dropdown that calls the same `searchFilter` function and should get the new `$orderr_by` argument, when the onchange event is triggered for `order_by` dropdown.

Below I have got it to work for three static arguments but I need to make it work when the `$orderr_by` argument is changed:

```
<select name="condition" id="condition" 
        onchange="searchFilter('<?php echo $pageNum;?>',
                               '<?php echo $maxRows;?>',
                               '<?php echo $orderr_by; ?>');">
```

My Axaj looks like this:

```
function searchFilter(pageNumbr,maxRows,order_by) {

    var filter  = jQuery.noConflict();

    filter.post(
        MYSURL+'ajaxphp/searchFilters.php?page_no='+pageNumbr+'&max_rows='+maxRows+'&order_by='+order_by, 
        filter('#filterFrm').serialize(), 

        function(html){  
            arrHtml = html.split('<####>');
            filter('#resultContainer').html(arrHtml[0]);    
        }
    );

    } // function searchFilter()
```

Comment: I'm not entirely following what you're trying to do. Are you trying to pass the value of order_by to the searchFilter called by [name=condition]?

Comment: yes, correct. I want to get the new variable of `order_by` and pass it to `condition` in the place of `'<?php echo $orderr_by; ?>'`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the value of the [name=order_by] element.

In pure JS you do this as follows:

```
var element = document.getElementById("order_by");
var order_by = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

jQuery has cleaner ways of doing this.

You do not need order_by in your function declaration. If you do for some reason need to pass order_by from other code, you have to make sure order_by is not already defined:

```
if (order_by === undefined) {
   ...
}
```